# How to report results from a linear mixed model "test of fixed effects" in SPSS?

Tags: mixed-model, spss, linear-model, reporting

What is the appropriate way to report results for linear mixed model based on the "test of fixed effects" table in SPSS?

Is it just (F=xxx, p=xxx)?

This isn't my data but this is an image I found of the output table I am talking about: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/test11.gif

[image]

Comment: and the parameter estimates... I'm pretty sure they're t tests, not F tests. Just report the fixed effects like you would in linear regression.

Comment: Can you paste in the output you are referring to?

Comment: @gung Sure, I just found an image online of a table (I cant figure out how to add my own)

Comment: Hi @gung thanks for inserting the table for me, but that table was just included per your request. I was wondering would the correct way to report this example data set for diet be (F=10.1, p=0.004)? I am not sure what you mean by the parameter estimates Patrick because I don't have a table reporting that in my output. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @PatrickCoulombe I am not sure what you mean by the parameter estimates because I don't have a table reporting that in my output. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you want to report it. AFAIK, there is no APA format for reporting LMMs.

Based on [this reference](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/309/Book/chapter15.pdf), the author chose to report `F` and `p` values alone. For example, he states:

> The “Tests of Fixed Effects” table, Table 15.6, shows that grade
>   (F=12.9, p=0.002) and stdTest (F=25.6, p<0.0005) each have a
>   significant effect on a student’s reading score difference, but
>   treatment (F=1.2, p=0.289) does not.

As you can see, he reported it as `(F=25.6, p<0.0005)` ignoring adding more details for the `F` value.

Your second option is to report it the same way `F` value is reported on APA style

```
F (numerator_df, denominator_df) = F_value, p = ...
```